# Docker - how to pass environment variables from docker compose at build time and best practices?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an app I am attempting to containerize that consists of a webapp with PostgreSQL, elasticsearch, and redis services. My webapp needs to populate data in the redis and elasticsearch services with data from Postgres before the app can be run, so I am using an entrypoint in my dockerfile for the app. To populate these services, my app uses the addresses of the services set by the docker compose network in its own(app-specific) settings files which I have set as environment variables in the docker compose `environment` section of the app to be passed into the container.

My `docker-compose.yml` file is as such:

```
version: '3'
services:

  redis:
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    expose: 
       - 6379:6379

 
  elasticsearch:
    image: 'docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.13.1'
    environment: 
      - node.name=node-1
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=node-1
    expose:
      - "9200:9200"

  db:
    image: 'postgres:latest'
    build:
      context: ./docker/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile   
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: myuser
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: trust
      POSTGRES_DB: mydb
 
  app:
    build: ./app
    ports:
      - '8000:8000'
    volumes: 
      - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql

    environment:
    - REDIS_HOST = redis
    - DB_NAME=mydbname
    - DB_USER=myusername
    - ES_URL = elasticsearch

    links:
      - redis
      - db 
      - elasticsearch
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - db
      - elasticsearch
```

The dockerfile for my app(relevant section) is as such, where the `entrypoint.sh` script contains the commands for populating these services:

```
# copy project
COPY . .
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh

#compile assets for testing and insert data from db into Elasticsearch and Redis
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

However, the addresses of these services don't seem to be passed as environment variables from `docker-compose.yml` and are not accessible by the app container when the entrypoint script is running, though in earlier builds(without the entrypoint script), they seem to have been passed into the container once it was up and running. I am somewhat confused here because as I understand it, entrypoint scripts are run as if they were in the running stage of the container and not the build stage, so they should have access to environment variables from `docker-compose.yml`.

There seem to be several options for passing environment variables during this stage, and I am not sure what is the best practice here, if a container needs to access other containers on the internal network before the final `CMD` statement where it is run and exposed.

Thanks

Comment: You **cannot** have access to other containers during the build phase: at that point you're not running in a "real" container; you're running in a build environment that is, by design, extremely isolated (because "docker build", and by extension the build feature of docker compose, which just calls out to docker, is meant to produce the same result wherever it's run).

Comment: I see. Is there a different design pattern I should be using here, to populate data in my other containers/services before the app service runs?

Comment: Which environment variables in particular are you trying to access? In which container? I'm unclear exactly what isn't working.

Comment: I am trying to access the environment variables defined in the docker-compose.yml file under the app service from the app container.

Comment: But where are you trying to access them? Do you want to access them from one of the other containers? Are they not visible in your `app` container (they should be)?

Comment: There are a couple of extra spaces in the `environment:` values which could be causing problems; you are setting a variable `REDIS_HOST ` (ending with a space as part of the variable name) to ` redis` (where the value begins with a space).  Does deleting these spaces help?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer, yet, since I'm waiting for some additional information from you. However, there are several issues with your existing configuration that I wanted to highlight:

- Don't use `links` in your compose file; that feature has been [deprecated](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/) for several years now. Docker maintains automatic DNS entries for containers on the same network so you can always refer to other services in your compose file by name.
- It looks like you've confused the `expose` and `ports` directives.

  The `expose` statement is effectively a no-op (it's informative for people reading your compose file, but otherwise not particularly useful).

  You publish ports using the `ports` directive. Instead of:

  ```
  expose:
    - "9200:9200"
  ```

  You want:

  ```
  ports:
    - "9200:9200"
  ```
- The short form of `depends_on` is also effectively useless. It makes a container depend on the successful startup of another container, but it doesn't know anything about the *services* in that container, so e.g. if you `depends_on` Postgres, you may still end up trying to interact with postgres before it's actually ready to accept connections.

  There is a [long form of `depends_on`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#long-syntax-1), but for this to be effective you need to implement health checks for your containers.

  Either use the long form, or implement connect-and-retry logic in your application.

It looks like you may be working from some old documentation; the [compose syntax reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/) is worth a read.

---

Rest of answer TBD pending updates to your question/comments...